# Algorithm implementation in C# seems to be catastrophic

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, performance, optimization

I was trying to implement the algorithm specified in this research paper : 
[here - please ignore the math, since its irrelevant to the question][2]. This algorithm is very basic in Formal Concept Analysis. The input is a matrix `NXM` stored as `X` and `.` in a .txt file. According to the pseudocode embedded in the paper, the input must be represented as a matrix as well

Comment: Assuming your actual test measurements ignore JIT time and you run release build without debugger... Next step would be to user profiler and see where most time spent... Generally such question will get someone interested and you get optimized version without any efforts on your side (also this is game of chance mostly).

Comment: Its not like I just want to optimize it, I need to understand whether C# is as good as c++ or I should depart .net world and move to another language which is designed around algorithms implementations

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably demonstrates the problem, you are unlikely to get any specific answer that helps. As far as whether _"C# is as good as C++"_, it certainly is but each language has its strengths and weaknesses. Still, even a naively-but-competently implemented version of a C++ algorithm should come within 10-20% of the performance of unmanaged code, and with effort (and possibly using `unsafe` code) should be able to achieve parity. A 35x difference is unheard of for a correctly-done port.

Comment: excuse me to bring this to you, but your comment lacks subjective contribution since the code is posted and the pseudo code also is available. `A 35x difference is unheard of for a correctly-done port` this statement is too weak to express @PeterDuniho

Comment: C# can get very close to C++.  Part of the problem is your port of the pseudo code isn't correct.

Comment: It's kind of hard to answer this without seeing the C++ source as a reference. Does your code produce the correct result?

Comment: can you explain ? @KeithNicholas

Comment: _"since the code is posted"_ -- please read the link I provided to learn what is meant by **a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example**. What you've posted here is not.

Comment: actually, it does, its just done really weird, if you could post a complete example that we can compile for ourselves, with expected output, then could refactor your code to be more normalish C#

Comment: Note that any question describing a performance difference between C++ and C# code _must_ include **good, _minimal_, _complete_ code examples** for _both_ languages.

Comment: just a small check - are you sure you have compiled the C# in release mode, too? debug-mode is usually the default and it has some performance hit.

Comment: Try timing your calls to alg() and generate_from() in Main separately. Which is responsible for most of the time?

Comment: Oh , My bad @PeterDuniho

Comment: In `generate_from`, new `int[] D`s are repeatedly allocated inside `for (int j` and `compute_closure`. The D is always `CT_WIDTH` size and never used anymore after each `j`-iteration. You can same some memory and GC time by reusing the Ds between `for(int j` loops and `calculate_closure` calls. Instead of `int[] D; /.../ D=compute_closure`, pre-create the D and pass it to the function: `int[] D = new int[xxx];  /.../  compute_closure(D, B, j)` + remove allocation of D from `closure`.. I doubt that's all, but a bit for sure.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl heh, I just made that exact optimization while looking at the code, but it doesn't help too much

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/97650/9357)

Answer (score 2):

Without being able to see the source to the C++ implementation that you are comparing against it's impossible to say for sure the reason why it is so much faster than your C# code, but since each of your values is either 0 or 1 then one optimization you can do (at the cost of making your code more complicated) is to store the values in some kind of bitmask data structure, or just as packed bit values in int arrays and use bit-manipulation operations to manipulate them. It's possible that the C++ implementation is doing this, but this isn't shown in the published pseudo-code for ease of explanation.

For example, since CT_WIDTH is 126, you can store a single row in 4 x 32-bit integers (128 bits), instead of 126 integers.

Then operations like this:

```
match = true;
for (int j = 0; j < CT_WIDTH; j++)
{
    if (B[j] == 1 && FCAContext[rows[y][i] * CT_WIDTH + j] == 0)
    {
        match = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Can be re-written like this, effectively processing 32 values at a time:

```
// CT_WIDTH_SHIFTED = (CT_WIDTH + 31) / 32
match = true;
int index = rows[y][i] * CT_WIDTH_SHIFTED;
for (int j = 0; j < CT_WIDTH_SHIFTED; j++)
{
    if (B[j] & FCAContext[index + j] != B[j])
    {
        match = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Likewise, this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < CT_WIDTH; j++)
    if (FCAContext[rows[y][i] * CT_WIDTH + j] == 0)
         D[j] = 0;
```

Can be rewritten as

```
for (int j = 0; j < CT_WIDTH_SHIFTED; j++)
    D[j] &= FCAContext[index + j];
```

The values in FCAContext, D and B need to be stored as packed bits.

For example, to set a bit in an array, instead of using code like this to set the jth element of an int array:

```
B[j] = 1;
```

you would first of all compute the index by dividing j by 32 by shifting left by 5 (j >> 5) and compute the bit inside the element like this 1 << (j & 31), which is one shifted right by the remainder of j divided by 32, then set it using a bitwise OR operation:

```
B[j >> 5] |= 1 << (j & 31)
```

[Here's](http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html) an online tutorial about bit masking. Google "bit manipulation", "bit shifting", "bit masking" "bit hacking" and "bit operations" / "bitwise operations" for more information. Bit manipulation can get pretty fiddly and makes your code hard to read however.

Also consider using the .NET [BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: can you please update your question to explain more about bitmasking ?

Comment: I just don't understand this `// CT_WIDTH_SHIFTED = (CT_WIDTH + 31) >> 5`

Comment: It calculates the number of 32 bit integers needed to store 126 bits. Adding 31 is to ensure that the value is rounded up, because it means that the result will be one greater, except for when CT_WIDTH is exactly divisible by 32. (126 + 31) / 32 = 4 (integer division)

Comment: Ok , but the 126 is not fixed , it depends on the input sometimes it will be like 4 or 60 or 200 ... etc

Comment: Yes, that's why it's a formula not a hardcoded value. for e.g. (60 + 31) / 32 = 2. (200 + 31) / 32 = 7 etc.

Comment: I think I get your idea , can you update your answer with the complete `compute_clousre()` ? I will mark it straightly as an answer.

Comment: I changed the entire work to BitArray , and now I keep getting type mismatch for this statement `int index = FCAContext[rows[y][i] * CT_WIDTH_SHIFTED];` since the value of FCAContext now is a bit which holds only true or false

Comment: It should just be index = rows[y][i] * CT_WIDTH; If you are using a BitArray then don't do the shifting and bit packing because that is done inside the BitArray class. You just access it like an array. It's an alternative to doing the bit-manipulation yourself.